# Erro ao conectar com banco de dados MySQL no Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Código da conexão:

```
package br.bent.jdbc;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class Conexao {

    private static Conexao conexao;

    public static Conexao getInstance(){
        if (conexao == null){
            conexao = new Conexao();
        }
        return conexao;
    }
    public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/consultab","root","root");
    } 
    public static void main(String[]args){
        try{
        System.out.println(getInstance().getConnection());
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Erro resultante:

```
Invalid authorization specification message from server: "Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2001)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1808)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at br.bent.jdbc.Conexao.getConnection(Conexao.java:20)
    at br.bent.jdbc.Conexao.main(Conexao.java:24)
```

Outro detalhe que não mencionei,é o seguinte estou usando o mysql workbench 6.3,e a versão do connector é 5.1 esso da erro.

Answer (score 1):

No caso o erro é de usuário e senha, o método `getConnection` recebe só String neste caso
[Doc Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Então no caso é só passar isso:

```
return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/consultab","root","123");
```

Comment: Agora tem outro detalhe eu estou usando o Mysql workbench 6.3 e o connector é a versão 5.1 isso da erro.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que na sua classe `Conexao`, você esqueceu de passar o usuário e a senha do banco de dados para o método `getConnection` da classe `DriverManager`. E por causa disso o seu MySQL recusou a conexão como pode ser visto por este texto:

> Invalid authorization specification message from server: "Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Que traduzindo para o português é:

> Mensagem do servidor de especificação de autorização inválida: "Acesso negado para o usuário 'ninguém'@'localhost' (usando senha: NÃO)"

Comment: A e é que ta minha senha e numero quando coloco da erro ex:("root",123);

Comment: @GleistonJosedeSantana Poste na sua questão então qual é o código da sua classe `Conexao`.